# Why Doesn't My Programmatically Set Relative Layout Positions Work Correctly?

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I want a 3x3 grid of views like this:

```
0 1 2
3 4 5
6 7 8
```

So I used the following code:

```
for (int i=0; i<9; i++) {
        View ns = (View)View.inflate(ctx, R.layout.view_layout, null);
        viewArray.add(ns);
        ns.setId(i);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        if (i>2) {
            if (i<6) {
                lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, viewArray.get(1).getId());
            }
            else {
                lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, viewArray.get(3).getId());
            }
        }
        if (i%3!=0) {
            lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, viewArray.get(viewArray.size()-2).getId());
        }


        //This shouldn't be necessary, but it is
        if (i==3) {
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            lp1.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, viewArray.get(3).getId());
            viewArray.get(1).setLayoutParams(lp1);
        }


        addView(ns, lp);

    }
```

This code currently works correctly, but only because of the "if (i==3)" section.  Without it, the 1 overlaps the 0 (so the RIGHT_OF isn't working correctly).  Any idea what the problem is?

Comment: An `id` of value 0 is not valid for a view. Change your iterator to start from 1 and adapt the code accordingly.

Comment: I just realised that it is pretty easy for you, there is no need to change the iterator ranges, just change `setId(i)` to `setId(i+1)` and it should work.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I did.